# database in async setup not working properly

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, async-await, fastapi

I am fairly new to FastApi and I am trying to setup an app to query some tables, I have setup an async session but when I try to query something the app freeze and crash after a while

```
def setup_database(app: FastAPI):
    # Init db
    engine = create_async_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, future=True, echo=True)
    app.state.database = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False,class_=DBSession)

async def request_db_session() -> AsyncIterator[DBSession]:
    from app import app
    db_session: DBSession = app.state.database()

    try :
        yield db_session
    finally:
        await db_session.close()

async def request_user(email: str, db_session: DBSession=Depends(request_db_session))
    user_query = await db_session.scalars(select(User).filter(User.email == email))
```

Moreover if I change the session to be sync instead of async the app works fine

```
def setup_database_sync(app: FastAPI):
    # Init db
    engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI_SYNC, future=True, echo=True)
    app.state.database_sync = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)

async def request_db_session_sync() -> DBSession:
    from app import app
    db_session: DBSession = app.state.database_sync()

    try :
        yield db_session
    finally:
       db_session.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

[FastAPI official documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/async-sql-encode-databases/#import-and-set-up-sqlalchemy) provided an example of how to deal with `async` databases connection using [databases module](https://www.encode.io/databases/) and `SQLAlchemy`

However, this is another variant of the same example using this tree structure and `SQLite`(databases module supports also `MySQL` database):

```
+---application
|   apis.py
|   app.py
|   asgi.py
|   models.py
```

**apis.py:**

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from app import app
from fastapi import status
from models import NotesModel, database
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Note(BaseModel):
    id: int
    text: str
    completed: bool


class NotePayload(BaseModel):
    text: str
    completed: bool


@app.get("/notes/", response_model=list[Note])
async def read_notes():
    query = sa.select(NotesModel)
    return await database.fetch_all(query)


@app.post("/add-notes/" status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def add_notes(data: NotePayload):
    query = sa.insert(NotesModel)
    await database.execute(query=query, values=data.model_dump())
```

**app.py:**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from models import database, engine, metadata


def create_app(engine):
    metadata.create_all(engine)
    return FastAPI(debug=True)


app = create_app(engine)


# More information about .connect() and .disconnect()
# https://www.encode.io/databases/connections_and_transactions/
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    await database.connect()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    await database.disconnect()
```

**asgi.py:**

```
import uvicorn

from apis import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

**models.py:**

```
import databases
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./test.db"

metadata = sa.MetaData()
engine = sa.create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL,
    connect_args={"check_same_thread": False},
)
database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)


Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class NotesModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'notes'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    text = sa.Column(sa.Text)
    completed = sa.Column(sa.Boolean)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.id}#{self.text}#{self.completed}'
```